# ngSwitch not working in ngFor

Tags: angular

I am trying to use ngSwitch within ngFor and it doesn't seem to be working.
Below is the Test code I Have written (Note: i am using Devextreme UI, hence the dx-* tags)

```html
<dx-tab-panel
    #tabPanel
    [dataSource]="companies"
    [selectedIndex]="0"
    [loop]="false"
    [animationEnabled]="true"
    [swipeEnabled]="true"
>

 <dxi-item [title]="item.Title" *ngFor="let item of currView">  
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="item.Title"> 
   <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="TARs"> 
    <p>TEST</p>
   </ng-container>
   <iframe *ngSwitchDefault [src]="item.Src | safeUrl"></iframe>
  </ng-container>  
 </dxi-item>
</dx-tab-panel>
```

Comment: Can you provide the error please ?

Comment: NOTE: the ngFor is  working correctly as expected.

Comment: @runit No error, when the item.Title value is TARs, i would expect to see <p>TEST,/p> which i do not.

Comment: you mean it shows the iframe?

Comment: yes correct, it shows the default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give single quotes `'TARs'` for string literals else it takes as a variable which will be undefined.

```
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'TARs'"> 
                <p>TEST</p>
            </ng-container>
```

Since it was getting undefined in switch case, it was going to default.